# Django-nonrel is not working with django 1.7

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

My project's backend support is Django 1.7 and my database support is mongodb.
To satisfy above requirement i need to install django-nonrel.
When I try to install django-nonrel with below command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

It is replacing my django 1.7 to django 1.5.

Please help.
New to django and Mongo db.

Comment: No, Django non-rel does not work with 1.7. In fact it does not work with any version: it is its own, modified, version of Django that is based on 1.5.

Comment: OK so Is there any alternative solutions.? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try install django nonrel 1.6 by running

`pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.6`

It works for me with base configuration provided from [here](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html)

And if you succeed with 1.7 - tell me how :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm no longer working on that project. But will try to install the same virtual environment.